# Avoid status bar overlap on all screens

Tags: android, ios, react-native, redux, react-redux

I want all screens on my app to appear below the status bar on both iOS and Android, so I'd either have to add a `StatusBar` component or a `paddingTop` to all my screens.

Is there a way to do this globally? Where is the appropriate top level component to add the `StatusBar` in a Redux app? (e.g. which part of https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/tree/master/examples/ReduxExample)?

Answer (score 43):

Step 1: Import Platform and StatusBar

```
import { Platform, StatusBar} from 'react-native';
```

Step 2: Add this style in parent View

```
paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'android' ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0
```

Full Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {
      Text, View,
      Platform, StatusBar
    } from 'react-native';

    export default class App extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={{ paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'android' ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0 }}>
            <Text>This is Text</Text>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hey just a quick thank you for posting this solution, I searched far and wide to find the solution to my problem and this was the only one that worked for sure.

Comment: Why just for iOS?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `<NavigationContainer/>` component to hold all your different pages, so that you don't need to duplicate the `StatusBar` and padding code in every single screen component.

I created a example in here:　https://snack.expo.io/SyaCeMOwW

And nothing need to change in term of your navigation structure or redux flow.

Comment: Which component should I wrap it around in a Redux Navigation app? Tried https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/blob/master/examples/ReduxExample/src/navigators/AppNavigator.js#L17 and https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/blob/master/examples/ReduxExample/index.js#L19, both didn't work (nothing renders)

Comment: @Avery235 You would want to wrap your LoginScree, MainScreen, ProfileScreen in this case, import the NavigationContainer in those page component and follow the example I have provided to put those page's component inside it.

Comment: This doesn't work because the React Navigation (which has a navigation bar) is wrapping around the components (LoginScreen etc)

Comment: @Avery235 hi there, I have the same problem with iOS, I tried almost everything but no luck, all pages are either in a stack navigator or tab navigator (nested), and in turn the top level navigator wrap with redux's store. Have you found a solution!?

Comment: @Yasir support this PR https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/pull/2446#issuecomment-336541787