# React Navigation - padding bottom on header not working

Tags: css, react-native, react-navigation, statusbar, searchbar

In my React-Native app I have an icon and [SearchBar](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/searchbar.html) in my header [(from react navigation)](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html).

The following code:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { params = {} } = navigation.state;
    return {
      headerTitle:
        <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "row", paddingHorizontal: 15, alignItems: "center" }}>
          <StatusBar default style={{ flex: 1, height: getStatusBarHeight() }} />
          <Icon name="chevron-left" size={28} />
          <SearchBar round platform={"default"} placeholder="Search" containerStyle={{
            flex: 1, backgroundColor: "transparent"
          }} />
        </View>,
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#e54b4d',
      }
    };
}
```

outputs this: [image]

So far so good. However, I want to have padding below the SearchBar. In other words, I want to have the distance from the top of the screen to the SearchBar as a padding below the SearchBar. (I can obtain the distance value using `getStatusBarHeight()` from [rn-status-bar-height](https://github.com/ovr/react-native-status-bar-height#readme))

However, if I put `paddingBottom: getStatusBarHeight()` to the `headerStyle`, I get this result:

[image]

Basically, now I have the padding that I wanted, however, the StatusBar overlaps with the SearchBar.

How can I put `paddingBottom` without making the StatusBar and SearchBar overlap?

Comment: Did you have chance to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45581440/avoid-status-bar-overlap-on-all-screens

Comment: Try to set `header` instead of `headerTitle` in the navigation options. Have you tried setting a `paddingTop` for the currently used element first. Honestly react-native header setting is a real pain.

Comment: @SubhenduKundu I have. However, it does not work for me.

Comment: @buddhiv I have tried setting paddingTop, however it does not apply any effect at all. I am currently trying to substitute it with `header`. Indeed it is causing me a lot of pain.

Comment: umm, try marginTop, works sometimes.

Comment: @buddhiv Playing a little with `header` instead of `headerTitle` worked out. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! I'm also pulling my hair out frequently for very simple fixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ios you will need to set backgroundColor.Below code is fit for android ios both.Hope it helps you.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { getStatusBarHeight } from 'react-native-status-bar-height';
import {
  Modal,
  Button,
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  StatusBar,
  Image,
  Platform,
} from 'react-native';
import { SearchBar, Icon } from 'react-native-elements';

export default class AssetExample extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { params = {} } = navigation.state;
    return {
      headerTitle: (
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? '#e54b4d' : '',
            alignItems: 'center',
            flexDirection: 'row',
            paddingHorizontal: 10,
            height: StatusBar.currentHeight,
          }}>
          <Icon name="chevron-left" size={28} />
          <SearchBar
            round
            platform={'default'}
            placeholder="Search"
            containerStyle={{
              flex: 1,
              backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            }}
          />
        </View>
      ),
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#e54b4d',
      },
    };
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' },
});
```

Answer (score 3):

To change the padding of the header in your case you'll need to change `headerTitleContainerStyle` and not **headerTitle**.

For example :

```
headerTitleContainerStyle: { paddingVertical: 10 }
```

You can still check the [doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#headertitlecontainerstyle).

Answer (score -1):

when i checked your code on my device its properly viewing with padding.

[image]

Comment: I do not have any problems with the header on Android. The problem is only on iOS.