# How to render react native app under the status bar?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am learning app development in react native and my app is overlapping with the status bar of my phone. If I add padding to the top then the padding would differ for different phones. I tried using SafeAreaView but it is not working and I read somewhere it only works for iPhones. So is there any way that I can render the app under the status bar? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**The app getting overlapped with the status bar**

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: You may refer to this issue https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/1314#issuecomment-361775086, hope this helps

Comment: Can you provide the code that you use to define the view and the navigation?

Comment: Refer [Avoid status bar overlap on all screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45581440/avoid-status-bar-overlap-on-all-screens)

Comment: Can you show me the screen code and router designation code where the problem is?

Comment: I am having the same issue, however when I build an apk, the app instance of the apk does not include the status bar

Answer (score 3):

You will need to find the statusbar height and set the top margin of your container to be equal to that amount.

Since Expo provides this value as a constant, you can use it to set the style of your parent component such that the content is always under the status bar.

You can follow this pattern from the github issue [here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/12#issuecomment-323577531)

```
const App = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  About: { screen: AboutScreen },
  }, {
    navigationOptions: { headerStyle: { marginTop: Expo.Constants.statusBarHeight } }
  })
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am using react-native-router flux for navigation and tried adding this style in the sceneStyle prop on my router tag.  But it gave me an error 'TypeError: undefined is not an object(Evaluating Expo.Constants.statusBarHeight)'

Comment: You need to install and import expo constants https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/constants/

Answer (score 3):

I finally solved it by simply adding `paddingTop:StatusBar.currentHeight` to the root view tag of my component.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `StatusBar` like this :

```
import { View, StatusBar } from 'react-native';

export const myComponent = () => {
    return (
         <View>
               <StatusBar backgroundColor={colors.SECONDARY_COLOR} />
               ... // your code
         </View>
    )
}
```

It will set the status bar backgroud color and it will prevent from overlaping your status bar.
If you don't want to set the background color you can just use :

```
<StatusBar />
```

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, I created a reusable component wrapper for my screen utilize both `SafeAreaView` and `View`. Sample code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, SafeAreaView, Platform, StatusBar } from 'react-native';

const styles = {
  container: { StatusBar.currentHeight }
};

/**
 * Screen Wrapper to apply padding space on status bar
 */
export const Screen = React.memo((props) => {
  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={props.style}>
        {props.children}
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }

  return (
    <View style={[styles.container, props.style]}>
      {props.children}
    </View>
  );
});
```

and then I simply use it wherever my screen needs that padding space. Simple and works.

```
render() {
  <Screen>
    <Text>{'your screen content here'}</Text>
  </Screen>
};
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I tried this method but this just gives me an 'Invariant Violation. Element type is invalid: expected a string or class but got undefined'. I am using react-native-router-flux for navigation.