# React Native android status bar

Tags: android, react-native

I'm new to React Native and I'm trying to get my text below the status bar of an android device. On my ios device, the "Hello World!" is perfectly right below the status bar, but on the android device, the "Hello World!" is right inside the status bar. Can anyone help me move the text so it can be below the status bar. Here is my code and what it currently look like on my android device.

```html
import React from "react";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { StyleSheet,Text,SafeAreaView,Platform } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.textColor}>Hello World!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)",
    alignItems: "center",
    paddingTop: Platform.OS === "android" ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0,
  },
  textColor: {
    color: "white",
  },
});
```

Current android view

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57765448/how-to-render-react-native-app-under-the-status-bar

Answer (score 2):

import StatusBar from react-native

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet,Text,SafeAreaView,Platform,StatusBar } from "react-native";
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default function App() {
  return (
   <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.textColor}>Hello World!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)",
    alignItems: "center",
    paddingTop: Platform.OS === "android" ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0,
  },
  textColor: {
    color: "white",
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`SafeAreaView` doesn't support `paddingTop` try to apply it to a `View`

```
<SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
  <View style={{ paddingTop: StatusBar.currentHeight }}>
    ...
  </View>
</SafeAreaView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried something different in combination with react-native-status-bar-height

```
import {Animated, Platform} from "react-native";
import {getStatusBarHeight} from "react-native-status-bar-height";
import React from "react";

const StatusbarAndroid = () => {
    return <Animated.View style={[{
        minHeight:0,
        height: Platform.OS === 'android' ? getStatusBarHeight() : 0}]}/>;
}

export default StatusbarAndroid;
```

Answer (score 0):

make the import from react-native

```js
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet,Text,SafeAreaView,Platform, StatusBar } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  console.log(StatusBar.currentHeight)
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.textColor}>Hello World!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </SafeAreaView>
    
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)",
    alignItems: "center",
    paddingTop: Platform.OS === "android" ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0,
  },
  textColor: {
    color: "white",
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also been dealing with this issue from time to time. The auto import usually imports it from expo-status-bar which doesn't work. The StatusBar needs to imported from 'react-native' for the styling to work. Something like this:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Text, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, StatusBar } from "react-native";

const HomeScreen = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Text>HomeScreen</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight || 0,
  },
});

export default HomeScreen;
```